# How to prove: $\exists x P(x) \implies Q(y) \Longleftrightarrow \forall x [P(x) \implies P(y)]$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am trying to prove the expression: $\exists x P(x) \implies Q(y) \Longleftrightarrow \forall x [P(x) \implies P(y)]$

I was hoping I could get some intimation on what to do next. For your time I am beforehand very appreciative.
I'll start proving first  $[\exists x P(x) \implies Q(y)] \implies \forall x [P(x) \implies P(y)]$

$$\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$$
[Existential Instantiation]
$$P(a) \to Q(y)$$
[Idempotency]
$$P(a) \wedge P(a) \to Q(y)$$
[Extraction]
$$P(a) \to (P(a) \to Q(y))$$
[Material Implication]
$$P(a) \to ( \neg P(a) ∨ Q(y)) $$
[DeMorgan]
$$P(a) \to \neg (P(a) \wedge \neg Q(y)) $$
[Simplification]
$$P(a) \to \neg (P(a))$$

This is as far as I've gotten. I seem to be really stuck. If anyone could provide me with suggestion on how to proceed from here I will greatly appreciate it. Thank you kindly.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an antecedant.  You must first deal with the conditional in $\color{grey}(\exists x~P(x)\color{grey})\to Q(y)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Could you explain why one cannot instantiate an antecedent? Also, $\exists xP(x) \to Q(y) \equiv \lnot \exists xP(x) \lor Q(y) \equiv \forall x \lnot P(x) \lor Q(y)$ - would this be the right way to go about it?

Comment: I would suggest you first figure out intuitively why it is true, and then try to convert that intuition into a formal proof.

Comment: The *Rules of Inference* apply *only* to whole statements.  They are not *Rules of Equivalence*, which are applied to (well-formed) parts of statements.$$~$$And yes, you are now on the right track.